# Trying to read a serialized file

Tags: java, file, arraylist, deserialization

I've been trying to read this file and add each object in an `ArrayList`. The problem is that it never goes inside the `while` loop.

Do you guys know what could be the problem? And may I improve the syntax of the code?

```
public ArrayList<Notificacion> obtenerListaNovedades() {
    ObjectInputStream ois = null;
    try {
        if (f.exists()) {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            while (true) {
                Notificacion notificacion = (Notificacion) ois.readObject();                    
                listaNotificaciones.add(notificacion);        
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("hay algo ene l archi");
        }           
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return listaNotificaciones;
}
```

Comment: Get rid of the redundant `f.exists()` test and put something useful into your empty `catch` block. Then you will know what went wrong.

Comment: It's because you've got an exception, put `e.printStackTrace()` inside the catch block and see what's caught.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That while loop will only exit when an exception occurs as well. It would be better to control the loop with a boolean, then catch the EOFException to exit the loop by setting the boolean to false. Something like:

```
boolean hasObjects = true;

while (hasObjects) {
    String notificacion = null;
    if (ois != null) {
        try {
            notificacion = (Notificacion) ois.readObject();
            listaNotificaciones.add(notificacion);
        } catch (EOFException e) {
            hasObjects = false;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        hasObjects = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What would be the correct boolean statement to put inside the while loop

Answer (score 1):

never just swallow up exceptions, otherwise you will not know what is going wrong

change to

```
catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace ();
}
```

Comment: The exception is: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 79737200. Do you what it means?

Comment: Thrown when control information that was read from an object stream violates internal consistency checks.  Maybe check you code for creating the file

Comment: `if (f.exists()) {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f, true);
                NotificacionH.AppendableObjectOutputStream oos = new NotificacionH.AppendableObjectOutputStream(fos);
                oos.writeObject(new Notificacion(id, diasLaborados, deducciones, fecha));
                return true;`

Comment: @Manuel Again you have a pointless `f.exists()` test here. In fact it's worse than that, as it will prevent you ever creating the file in the first place. Don't write code like this. Surely it's obvious that `new FileInputStream()` must itself check for the existence of the file, and its readability, etc., and that `new FileOutputStream()` must similarly check for the ability to create the file?

Answer (score 0):

Your most likely getting an exception when attempting to read the file and because your not doing anything with the exception, you don't know what is going on. At the very least, print the contents of the exception to the console and have a look:

```
e.printStackTrace();
e.getMessage();
```

So, again, have a look at the exception and go from there.